# How to extract href from element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, element

I am trying to extract both the href and the name from the html element.

```
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var $link = $row.find("td").eq(0).html();
    var $website = ????
    var $vendor = ????
```

$link returns `<a href="https://<website>/" target="_blank">'vendor name'</a>`

I want $website to return `https://<website>/` and $vendor to return `vendor name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
var $link = $row.find("td").eq(0).find('a'); // .html() returns a string, you don't want it. You want the jQuery reference of the link, so you can call jQuery methods on it
var $website = $link.attr('href');
var $vendor = $link.text();
```

Comment: This works but the href is displaying as undefined?

Comment: Figured it out! Just had to add var $website = $link.find("a").attr("href");

Comment: yeah, if `a` is inside of the td of course (updated) :)